# Dundas Charts Formatting Numbers on X Axis and Y Axis

Tags: dundas

I am using Dundas Charts and I am displaying a Bar Chart with X Axis and Y Axis as numbers. We want to show commas for numbers. For example 500000 can be shown as 500, 000. Any ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

use labelformat property as in

```
currentChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "d";
```